# PHP redirect not working?

Tags: php, mysql

Everytime I submit login.php (the code below) it fails and shows the die message.

```
<?php

  require("common.php");

  $submitted_username = '';

  if(!empty($_POST))
  {
      $query = "
          SELECT
              id,
              username,
              password,
              salt,
              email
          FROM users
          WHERE
              username = :username
      ";

      $query_params = array(
          ':username' => $_POST['username']
      );

      try
      {

          $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
          $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    true.
    $login_ok = false;

    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row)
    {
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']);
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
        {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
        }

        if($check_password === $row['password'])
        {
            // If they do, then we flip this to true
            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }


        unset($row['salt']);
        unset($row['password']);

      whether

        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;


        flush();
        header("Location: http://www.gzuga.com/User_System/private.php");
        die('should have redirected by now');        }
    else
    {
        // Tell the user they failed
        print("Login Failed.");

        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}

 ?>
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <form action="login.php" method="post">
       Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" />
     <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
 </form>
 <a href="register.php">Register</a>
```

Comment: what is the message you get?

Comment: And what error does `$ex->getMessage()` give in the `die`?

Comment: what exactly is `true.` and  `whether`? Those are going to cause an outright syntax errors and kill the script.

Comment: Your code block contains two strange things: at 1/3 it says `true.` just plain without any code. At 2/3 of the code it says `whether`....

Comment: This is the full version of the code http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies-167/program-basic-secure-login-system-using-php-mysql-891201.html